# Where to put a dev-only value?

Tags: 2010, development, configuration, environment

I'm using Ninject in a SharePoint feature. I've got it working via an HttpModule.

I need to tell Ninject whether I want to use my real or "fake" implementations.

I'm thinking about using a web.config appSetting value to drive that decision. My thinking is that the modification I manually make to my dev SP instance's web.config won't make it into source control or the deployed package.

I understand that manual web.config changes are a no-no in SP. Is this a valid exception?

Where do you put values that you want to exist only in your development environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint offers developers with many options for storing custom configurations settings outside of the application itself. This may vary from Web.config to Property Bags to Lists. I would personally recommend  to use Property Bags (Perhaps Web application/Farm level) to store configurations.

Here are some sample on how to use them: http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/

Read more about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855123(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I second the property bag implementation, because it's where sharepoint's own patterns and practices group puts depenedency injection data for it's custom dependency injection framework.

Comment: The reason why we are a bit hesitant to go with the web.config approach is two-fold: Manipulating web.config programmatically is often troublesome using SPWebConfigModification, as I’m sure several folks from community can attest from their previous engagements with similar issues ;-). Secondly, using either the ages-old “copyappbincontent”-approach and/or the *.config-injection are not really something that would work for every scenario, or even properly at times.

Comment: I like the property bag approach. It's very simple, and it can very easily be set using a simple Powershell script (ok for dev)

Answer (score 1):

Lance, I think web.config is the right approach to adding a value that is unique to an environment. We do exactly that in our environment and our deploy process handles the web.config files as well. You could also create a [supplemental web.config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439965.aspx). You could also [modify them programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439965.aspx).